# Moving element to cursor position gets logged, but the change of position is not applied

Tags: javascript, oop, settimeout

I have an object with chainable functions, it works ok-ish. Clicking on the triangle itself trigger an animation and translates the element accordingly.
Now I have another function which should translate the triangle to the current mouse position, the js is the following:

```
moveToTarget: function(e) {
var mouseX = 0, 
mouseY = 0,
xp = 0,
yp = 0;
xp += (mouseX - xp) / 12;
yp += (mouseY - yp) / 12;
block.style.left = xp + 'px';
block.style.top = yp + 'px';
setTimeout(moveToTarget,30);

return this;
```

Keep in mind this is just one of the methods on the object animateBlock and I am not sure if I have to call it as animateBlock.moveToTarget in that SetTimeout.

This is the invocation:

```
container.addEventListener("click", function(e){
console.log(e.pageY); // this log the Y position
animateBlock.moveToTarget;});
```

I get no JS lint errors, no runtime errors thrown in console, it just does not apply the translation for some reason, what am I missing here?

The Link:

https://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/MvvXoq

Comment: In this example : `xp += (mouseX - xp) / 12;` evaluates `xp` to `0`. Same with `yp`, maybe that's why. Also, `animateBlock.moveToTarget;});` doesn't call `moveToTarget`.

Comment: I have changed the mouxeX to e.pageX etc, still no luck. I accindentally had the initialization deleted.

Comment: added animateBlock.moveToTarget(); still no luck. I will try to get the position of the block div and calculate from there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mMXwwV?editors=0111

I had to make several changes, so my apologies:

- You were calling moveToTarget() without its parameter, the `event`
- The moveToTarget() function wasn't doing anything. You weren't using `event`, so the values were always 0.
- I removed the margin: 50% 0; from the triangle, since it messed with its X position (making using translateX() difficult).
- I put the "px" directly inside the function, so the parameters are only numbers now.
- New function moveXAndY() so to modify both translateX() and translateY() at the same time (otherwise they'd overwrite each other).
- Code's kind of a mess, I'm not used to editing on CodePen, so apologies for that.

Comment: Ah thanks, that one is much better than mine was. Yup, the (e) was not there. So, just to be sure, e.pageX returns a number, not a string? Thanks